# How to use APOC library in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-spatial

I installed the APOC library onto my Neo4j desktop, and when calling `apoc.help("")`, I get a list of all the APOC functions, so this tells me the installation was successful.

But when trying to run this:

```
CALL apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce('21 rue Paul Bellamy 44000 Nantes France')
```

I get the error:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.spatial.geocode`: Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuildException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This article may help: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/ldap-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target

Comment: is there another solution, this did not work for me?